# Raspberry Pi cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, sd-card, linux, kernel

I have a 16 MINI SD CARD been used in my Raspberry Pi . I currently have a few programs installed like vim and etc which should only take up around 300mb in total. Why does it say my /root directory is full even when I am using 16 GB SD CARD ? I am using Raspian OS .

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       3.7G  3.5G  4.3M 100% /
devtmpfs        459M     0  459M   0% /dev
tmpfs           463M     0  463M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           463M  6.3M  457M   2% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           463M     0  463M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1   60M   20M   41M  34% /boot
tmpfs            93M     0   93M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the command `sudo raspi-config` and select the `Expand Filesystem` option. Then you should be good to go.

Comment: You are the man Patrick!

Comment: FYI I just ran into this problem and the option I selected in `raspi-config` was `3 Boot Options    Configure options for start-up` so it seems the naming has changed a bit.